# Sturm-Liouville problem on unit disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Where can I find some information about: find the eigen values and eigen vectors $(\lambda,u)$ of the Sturm-Liouville problem

-$div(\rho^{\alpha+1}\nabla u)=\lambda\rho^\alpha u$

where $\alpha>-1$ and $\rho(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2$?

I'm working on $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\;x^2+y^2\leq1\}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you mean that you are working on the unit *disk* in $\mathbb{R}^2$?  Also, what is $\rho$?  The radius?

Comment: thanks @hardmath , I added the missing information.

Comment: The unit *disk* is the finite region bounded by the unit circle, so I feel sure that you meant to pose this PDE on that region (rather than on its boundary, where $\rho = 0$ according to your formula).

Comment: (edited) do you know where can I find information about this kind of problems?

Comment: I see it is a self-adjoint type of PDE, when converted to divergence form.  Are you more interested in the specific spectrum of this operator, or in some references about similar PDE operators?

Comment: To begin, I am interested in finding the values ​​and eigenvectors. I suppose it is necessary to transform the pde to polar form.